# Running a search to identify member

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm essentially trying to join single records in `tableA` based on information in `tableB`. If I get more than one result with the original joining conditions then I add more and rerun the query. If I get no results, then nothing transfers. ex: Search for `a.FRST_NM = b.FRST_NM`. If one result, pull the record. If more than one, add `LAST_NM` and if one result, pull that record. So on and so forth until I have one record. I can do one at a time, but this occurs 2 or 3 times per pass.

This is because some fields aren't populated in one table but are in the other. I just don't know how to add joining conditions without rewriting the entire `FROM` statement, or how to only pull the record if there's only one result.

```
IF(CONDITION_1 from JOIN_1) = 1 result THEN a.field_1 = b.field_1 and a.field_2 = b.field_2 

IF (CONDITION_1 from JOIN_1) > 1 result THEN (additional joining conditions + JOIN_1) as JOIN_1a 

ELSE IF(CONDITION_1 from JOIN_1a) = 1 result then a.field_1 = b.field_1 and    a.field_2 = b.field_2

IF(CONDITION_1 from JOIN_1) = 0 results then NO MOVE

--(Repeat with different tables and joining conditions)--
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  One method would be to join on one field and then prioritize based on the other fields.  Another would be to use `left join`.  That would look like:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2a.col, t2b.col, t2c.col) as col
from t1 left join
     t2 t2a
     on t1.col1 = t2a.col1 and t1.col2 = t2a.col2 and t1.col3 = t2a.col3 left join
     t2 t2b
     on t1.col1 = t2b.col1 and t1.col2 = t2b.col2 and t2b.col1 is null left join
     t2 t2c
     on t1.col1 = t2c.col1 and t2b.col1 is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
       *
       ,CASE WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM THEN 'matched' ELSE 'not matched' END LastNameMatchedExample
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 
                CASE
                    WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM AND a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND a.Field2 = b.Field2 AND a.Field3 = b.Field3 THEN 0
                    WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM AND a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND a.Field2 = b.Field2 THEN 1
                    WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM AND a.Field1 = b.Field1 THEN 2
                    WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM THEN 3
                    ELSE 4
                END
             ) as RowNumber
    FROM
       TableA a
       INNER JOIN TableB b
       ON a.FIRST_NM = b.FIRST_NM
    ) results
WHERE
    results.RowNumber = 1
```

So basically it does a search only on the First_NM criteria and then builds and order by list that allows you to pick the exact record you want based on if this matches and this matches and this matches etc.  So no matter how many records are returned you can then get the first result.  Because everything is coming from the same 2 tables you should always maintain the most amount of columns that you want and you can use CASE STATEMENTS to make a value NULL if no match etc.

below is a similar method that will handle a precedence of the field but sort of treats it like OR condition with other fields matching.  So in this example it will sort by existence of a match existence of a match etc. and walk through all of your statements.  Where it will differ from above is say that no LAST_NM match occurs but on one record a field1 match occurs and on another it doesn't it will make the field1 a match a higher result.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
       *
       ,CASE WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM THEN 'matched' ELSE 'not matched' END LastNameMatchedExample
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN a.LAST_NM = b.LAST_NM THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                ,CASE WHEN a.Field1 = b.Field1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                ,CASE WHEN a.Field2 = b.Field2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                ,CASE WHEN a.Field3 = b.Field3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
             )
    FROM
       TableA a
       INNER JOIN TableB b
       ON a.FIRST_NM = b.FIRST_NM
    ) results
WHERE
    results.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: So instead of changing the joining conditions, I would make CASE expressions instead? That actually sounds easier. Especially since in the later passes some tables are removed, and others are added in their place.

Comment: this assumes that all tables you will want to search are joined in the beginning as LEFT JOINs and then you just choose the record you want by creating a row_number() precedence to set the precedence based on case statements.  But you still have to have all of the tables joined in the beginning...

Comment: This works for the first pass, but the later passes have me removing tables and joining to different ones to run if there are >1 or =0 results.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  This is a row precedence method, so you would LEFT JOIN all of your tables in 1 query and then use this method to identify which record you want.  And I know that it works because I use it all of the time so if it is not working for you perhaps you can post your code and I can help you make sure you are coding to correctly for this technique